# JSF and placeholder jsf 2.2

Tags: jsf, placeholder

I am using jsf 2.2 in javaee project, i want to use a placeholder for my input text so that's what i used.

```
     <h:inputText id="nom" value="#{InscriptionBean.nom}" placeholder="test">
     </h:inputText>
```

but that's not working i also tried

```
     <h:inputText id="nom" value="#{InscriptionBean.nom}" h:placeholder="test">
     </h:inputText>
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following attribute to add a placeholder to your tag:

```
p:placeholder="test"
```

But what are `p` and `h`?
You need to declare the right tag library at the start of your view file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
```

The generated output would be:

```
<input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="test">
```

But double check if you are using jsf 2.2 (this may not work in lower versions)

Answer (score 0):

Add xmlns to page header :

```
xmlns:t="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

and use it like following :

```
<h:inputText id="nom" value="#{InscriptionBean.nom}" t:placeholder="test" />
```